# Synonymize/merge [treaty] and [treaties]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

We have both a [treaty](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/treaty) (8 questions) and [treaties](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/treaties) (30 questions) tags. They're obviously used for the same topic; can they be synonymized or merged?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[treaty](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/treaty) and [treaties](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/treaties) have now been merged and synonymised.

Answer (score 8):

Seems sensible.

If this is done, it seems like [treaties](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/treaties) would be the one to keep as the master, since it both has more questions on it and actually has a tag wiki.

---

An aside on process:

It looks like the intended process is supposed to be:

1. Suggest a tag synonym in the tag interface
2. Users of that tag approve it.
3. The synonym seems to be working well - post a meta question asking to merge the synonym into the main.
4. Moderators agree its working well, and perform the merge.

That being said, I'm not sure we're large enough for this process to work out for every tag, so yes, asking here for the entire shebang to be done by a mod works too. I just wanted to lift the process up for those who might not have been aware.

Comment: As a moderator, you can single-handledly establish a tag synonym. Common practice on Stack Exchange is to use the plural form.

Comment: @Glorfindel - It seems to be the cow-path here too, since the plural form had way more people use it, which I think indicates that's the form most users expect/use. So I guess we're affirming the "common practice". We of course can't use plurals only by policy, because most of our taggable subjects are inherently single (eg: France).